# How to convert Outlook messages to text maintaining double-byte character set?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a code to convert outlook emails into text. Works great except for emails received with DBCS (double-byte character set) from CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) languages.

The code I have is as follows:

```
Sub SaveAsTXT(myMail As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim myFolder As Folder

    ' Get sender email address
    senderEmAddress = myMail.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress

        If Not TypeName(myItem) = "Nothing" Then
               strname = myMail.Subject
               strdate = Format(myMail.ReceivedTime, "yymmddhhmmss")
               myMail.SaveAs "C:\folder\" & strdate & ".txt", olTXT
        End If
End Sub
```

I need to keep the extract as text. If I copy the email manually into notepad the CJK characters are copied correctly and saved correctly if I use UTF-8.

What can I add in the VBA code to capture the CJK characters correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the `MailItem.Body` property (like all COM strings, it is UT-16), explicitly build the header, combine it with the message body, and save the file yourself.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) is an option, its version of `SaveAs(..., olTxt)` does not have this problem:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
set msg = Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(myItem)
msg.SaveAs "c:\temp\test.txt", olTxt
```